# the loop runs only once

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a problem with my code. The loop runs only once respective of the number the user enters. Thanks for the help.

```
#create an empty list and ask the user how many items they want to add  
# take the items the user entered and add it to the empty list.
print("enter the number of items")
x = int(input(">")) #take number of user input with the type int
print("thanks")
print("enter your food items")
fitems = [] # empty list
for i in range(x): #range to limit the number of iteration the user entered.
    items = input (">") #taking the items from the user 
    empty = ""
    if (items == empty):# checking if the user added nothing
        print("no items added")
    break
else:
    fitems.append(items) #add the list of items the user entered to the 
empty list
    print("hello here is your food items: \n",fitems) #output user items
```

Comment: Regardless of what happens in your `for` loop, the indentation of `break` guarantees that it breaks after the first iteration. Perhaps you meant to indent it to be inside the `if` condition.

Comment: You have your `break` command at the main level inside your `for` loop, so it is definitely executed the first time the loop is executed and the loop ends. Try indenting the `break` statement one more level, to put it inside the preceding `if` statement, and see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty to make some changes. Try this out:

```
# create an empty list and ask the user how many items they want to add  
# take the items the user entered and add it to the empty list.

fitems = []

# Define valid input for amount of items
valid = [str(i) for i in range(1,10)] # ["1","2"...."9"]

# If item is not in the list of valid, continue asking
while True:
    print("enter the number of items [1-9]")
    x = input(">")
    if x in valid:
        break

# Convert to int
itemamount = int(x)
print("thanks\nenter your food items")

# Now ask for inputs using while > 0 and remove itemamount in each loop
while itemamount > 0:
    while True:
        item = input (">")
        if item:
            break
        print("Blank input")
    fitems.append(item)
    itemamount-=1

print("hello here is your food items: ")
for ind,i in enumerate(fitems,1):
    print("{}. {}".format(ind,i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some indentation in your code and there are also some other mistakes. This is (I think) the correct code:

```
print("enter the number of items")
x = int(input(">"))
print("thanks")
print("enter your food items")
fitems = []
for i in range(x):
    items = input(">").strip() # there was a space before first bracket in your code, it's possible to have it there, but this is better
    # edit: added .strip(), it removes extra whitespace from beginning and end
    if items == "": # no need to create empty string variable, compare simply with empty string,
    # edit: you can also use 'if not items:', because empty string evaluates to false
        print("no items added")
        break # break only if nothing added, so indent break to be only executed if empty
    fitems.append(items) # you don't have to have else here, break ends the loop, so this is not executed then
print("hello here are your food items: \n",fitems) # remove 1 indent, print only after loop ended
```

Comment: `if (items == ""):` has unnecessary parentheses and would, in most cases, be better to just check for something falsey. `if not items:` is more pythonic.

Comment: works great but i would like for the print statement to print everything after the user has entered the item instead of printing one one and finally printing everything.

Comment: @roganjosh parentheses are there because I was writing some JS recently. As for `not items`, my dad (python programmer) says I abuse this behaviour and I should use comparation because it's transparent for anyone who reads the code.

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine I'm not sure if I understand you... Now, the code prints all items after loop ended. If you want it to print all items every time user add an item, add one indent level (4 spaces) before the last `print` statement, so it gets inside the loop and execute in every iteration.

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine I see you're new to Stack Overflow, so here's one tip - if this (or any other, of course) answer solved your problem and you find it the best, mark it as accepted (tick). See [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: @M.Volf thanks for the tip. As you can see i am a newbie here. hopefully i will get used to as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, Since you have not indented the "break" inside the for loop

```
#create an empty list and ask the user how many items they want to add  
 # take the items the user entered and add it to the empty list.
 print("enter the number of items")
 x = int(input(">")) #take number of user input with the type int
 print("thanks")
 print("enter your food items")
 fitems = [] # empty list
 for i in range(x): #range to limit the number of iteration the user entered.
    items = input (">") #taking the items from the user 
    empty = ""
    if (items == empty):# checking if the user added nothing
       print("no items added")
       break #your error corrected
    else:
       fitems.append(items) #add the list of items the user entered to the 
  empty list
    print("hello here is your food items: \n",fitems) #output user items
```

Comment: works great but i would like for the print statement to print everything after the user has entered the item instead of printing one one and finally printing everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem in your code is the identation, so you should change like this:

```
print("enter the number of items")
x = int(input(">")) #take number of user input with the type int
print("thanks")
print("enter your food items")
fitems = [] # empty list
for i in range(x): #range to limit the number of iteration the user ente red.
    items = input (">") #taking the items from the user 
    empty = ""
    if (items == empty):# checking if the user added nothing
        print("no items added")
        break
    else:
        fitems.append(items) #add the list of items the user entered to the 

print("hello here is your food items: \n",fitems)
```

Comment: works great but i would like for the last print statement not to print after nothing is entered by the user

Answer (score 0):

First of all break statement and else statement aren't intended properly. Furthermore when you use .append() you should add a i+=1 to loop through x , that the user inputs.

This will work :

```
for i in range(x): #range to limit the number of iteration the user entered.
    items = input (">") #taking the items from the user
    empty = ""
    if (items == empty):# checking if the user added nothing
        print("no items added")
        break
    else:
        fitems.append(items) #add the list of items the user entered to the
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will result in a no-print if nothing was entered:

```
print("enter the number of items")
x = int(input(">")) #take number of user input with the type int
print("thanks")
print("enter your food items")
fitems = [] # empty list
for i in range(x): #range to limit the number of iteration the user entered.
    items = input (">") #taking the items from the user 
    empty = ""
    if (items == empty):# checking if the user added nothing
        print("no items added")
        break
    else:
        fitems.append(items) #add the list of items the user entered to the\
                                                                empty list
if len(fitems)==0:
    pass
else:
    print("hello here is your food items: \n",fitems)
```